# Iterating over two dfs and add values

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe along the lines of the below (df1):

```
     Country  Crisis
1    Italy     2008
2    Germany   2008, 2009
3    Mexico     
4    US        2007
5    Greece    2010, 2007
```

I have another dataframe (df2) in panel data format:

```
    Country       Year
1    Italy        2007
2    Italy        2008  
3    Italy        2009
4    Italy        2010
5    Germany      2007
6    Germany      2008  
7    Germany      2009
8    Germany      2010
9    Mexico       2007
10    Mexico      2008  
11    Mexico      2009
12    Mexico      2010
13    US          2007
14    US          2008  
15    US          2009
16    US          2010
17    Greece      2007
18    Greece      2008  
19    Greece      2009
20    Greece      2010
```

I wish to add a column to df2, "crisis", in which 1 will indicate a crisis, like so:

```
    Country       Year      crisis
1    Italy        2007         0
2    Italy        2008         1
3    Italy        2009         0
4    Italy        2010         0
5    Germany      2007         0
6    Germany      2008         1
7    Germany      2009         1
8    Germany      2010         0
9    Mexico       2007         0
10    Mexico      2008         0
11    Mexico      2009         0
12    Mexico      2010         0
13    US          2007         1
14    US          2008         0
15    US          2009         0
16    US          2010         0
17    Greece      2007         1
18    Greece      2008         0
19    Greece      2009         0
20    Greece      2010         1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451), make an earnest effort, and come back with a *specific* question with code attempt. There are numerous pandas questions regarding splitting comma separated data.

Comment: my idea was something like: for index, row in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(df1.iterrows()):
    country=(row[0])
    years=(row[1])
    years=years.split(", ")
    i=0
    for year in range(len(years)):
        df2.loc[(df2.Country==country) & (df2.Year == years[i]), 'economic_crisis'] = 1
    i+=1

Comment: Please [edit] your question with relevant code instead of posting code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Although not pretty, this works:

```py
df2['crisis'] = df2.groupby('Country', sort=False, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['Year'].isin(df1[df1['Country'] == x['Country'].iloc[0]]['Crisis'].iloc[0])).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
    Country  Year  crisis
1     Italy  2007   False
2     Italy  2008    True
3     Italy  2009   False
4     Italy  2010   False
5   Germany  2007   False
6   Germany  2008    True
7   Germany  2009    True
8   Germany  2010   False
9    Mexico  2007   False
10   Mexico  2008   False
11   Mexico  2009   False
12   Mexico  2010   False
13       US  2007    True
14       US  2008   False
15       US  2009   False
16       US  2010   False
17   Greece  2007    True
18   Greece  2008   False
19   Greece  2009   False
20   Greece  2010    True

>>> df2.assign(crisis=df2['crisis'].astype(int))
    Country  Year  crisis
1     Italy  2007       0
2     Italy  2008       1
3     Italy  2009       0
4     Italy  2010       0
5   Germany  2007       0
6   Germany  2008       1
7   Germany  2009       1
8   Germany  2010       0
9    Mexico  2007       0
10   Mexico  2008       0
11   Mexico  2009       0
12   Mexico  2010       0
13       US  2007       1
14       US  2008       0
15       US  2009       0
16       US  2010       0
17   Greece  2007       1
18   Greece  2008       0
19   Greece  2009       0
20   Greece  2010       1
```